# BlueZ Mgmt API: "Add Extended Advertising Parameters Command" returns Unknown command

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, bluez

I am facing the below issue:
When I am sending Bluez mgmt api "Add Extended Advertising Parameters Command" from the host it's returning as "Unknown command" as status.

I am using
BlueZ version 5.64 [bluetoothd -v = 5.64]
Linux kernel version 5.4.x
as per the Bluez documentation, supported Bluez management api version is 1.14

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n2618

Is there any compatibility issues between the above versions or did I missed any pre-condition command to execute before this command ?

Thanks in advance.

my code is looks like this.

```
char buf_write[24] = {0x54,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x12,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0C};

size_t length = write(socketDescriptor, command, commandSize);

here socketDescriptor = socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_CLOEXEC | SOCK_NONBLOCK, BTPROTO_HCI);
```

Note: when the above code is executed I received length = 0 for unknown command scenario, but when other successful scenarios (Ex: Get PHY Configuration (0x0044)) the length = commandsize.

btmon trace:

```
@ MGMT Command: Add Extended Advertising Parameters (0x0054) plen 18
{0x0002} [hci0] 769.600316
        Instance: 1
        Flags: 0x00004002
          Advertise as Discoverable
          Use provided interval parameters
        Duration: 0
        Timeout: 0
        Min advertising interval: 100.000 msec (0x00a0)
        Max advertising interval: 100.000 msec (0x00a0)
        TX power: 12 dbm (0x0c)
@ MGMT Event: Command Status (0x0002) plen 3
{0x0002} [hci0] 769.600333
      Add Extended Advertising Parameters (0x0054)
        Status: Unknown Command (0x01)
```

When I executed same command from hcitool its returned success.

```
< HCI Command: ogf 0x08, ocf 0x0036, plen 25
  00 13 00 A0 00 00 A0 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F 
  01 00 01 00 01 
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (0x08|0x0036) plen 25                                                                                                        #390 [hci0] 2328.752727
        Handle: 0x00
        Properties: 0x0013
          Connectable
          Scannable
          Use legacy advertising PDUs: ADV_IND
        Min advertising interval: 100.000 msec (0x00a0)
        Max advertising interval: 100.000 msec (0x00a0)
        Channel map: 37, 38, 39 (0x07)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
        Filter policy: Allow Scan Request from Any, Allow Connect Request from Any (0x00)
        TX power: Host has no preference (0x7f)
        Primary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        Secondary max skip: 0x00
        Secondary PHY: LE 1M (0x01)
        SID: 0x00
        Scan request notifications: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 5                                                                                                                                        #391 [hci0] 2328.756594
      LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters (0x08|0x0036) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        TX power (selected): 12 dbm (0x0c)
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276266/7721752) your question to show how you are issuing the command